# What is the purpose of red / white lights in ISS / SpaceX Dragon docking?

Tags: spacex, iss

I'm watching the [live TV from NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/index.html#public) broadcasting the ISS / SpaceX Dragon docking and I've seen a red light and a white flashing light. See them at the bottom of this image

[image: screenshot from NASA live TV].

What are they for?

Comment: Navigation lights.  If you see a spaceship the red/green split, and white tail mast tells you direction it is going.  (Making a bad boating joke here).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Navigation lights. Red on port, green on starboard, white on top, and yellow on bottom. The white light is also usually used as a tracking light from distance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_light

Comment: Really?  Red/Green/white?  Just like a boat!  I was joking earlier!  Yellow for the bottom that is not useful on a boat.  Cool.

Comment: @geoffc -- And just like an airplane. The similarity is intentional, as are the terms docking and berthing.